# Find the row and append to the bottom of the file

Tags: sed, grep, cat

I have a big file with some record which will be having different values than others.

**Actual data file:**

```
000000106500000000000129201300000U1E4600000060000+00000020400+00000002532+000000
0000001065000000000001182013000010144700002090000+00000335156+00000006776+000000
0000001065000000000003012014999999999924835390500+07164327872+00447479302+000000
0000001065000000000001102013000004QE8200000150000+00000056450+000000021
```

> $ grep -n "9999999999" BADINS0000001065_000000000020140301.dat

I wanted to append this record into bottom of the file, simply if I have ~100 records in file if my record position is somewhere in the file, I have to find, remove from that location (completely) and need to be appended to end of the file (Bottom of the file).

There are many files in directory I want to make it automate this process for every run. File name is BADINS0000001065_0000000000*  always same.

Would you please help me to achieve this?

Comment: How many "bad" records do you expect in each file? More than one?

Comment: Also, show your desired output. Then everyone will be clear about what you want.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you can do:

```
awk '
  /PATTERN/ { save = $0 ; next }
  { print }
  END { print save }
' infile > outfile
```

where you have to replace `PATTERN` by the actual pattern and `infile` is your data file; rename those appropriately.

The code works as follows:

`/PATTERN/ { save = $0 ; next }` - if the pattern is found save this line for later use and skip printing (so it's removed from this place)

`{ print }` - prints those lines in the file that have not been skipped by the previous command

`END { print save }` - finally, when all lines are processed, append the saved line, the one where the pattern matched

If you want to overwrite the  original file by the new file add a `mv` command after the `awk` script:

```
mv outfile infile
```

again with appropriately chosen filenames.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I have to keep the row at the bottom of the file(There are n number of records in file)

Comment: @Mahesh; I don't understand your comment. - I'll add an explanation in my answer, in case it's unclear.

Comment: Note that this will add a blank line to the bottom of the file, if no `PATTERN` line is found.

Comment: @Peter.O; if you want to cover that case do the final print conditionally: `END { if(save) print save }`.

Answer (score 1):

Other sed solution

```
sed -i '
        /9999999999/{h;d};           # move match string in hold space
        $G;                          # append string from hold space to end
        s/\n$//                      # avoid empty line if pattern have not met 
       ' BADINS0000001065_0000000000*
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear on whether or not the `9999999999` is always present, or whether there can be more than one such instance in the input file. So here is a `sed` version which caters for all of these situations.
See `man sed` (option `-i`) for in-place update of the input file.

```
sed -n '/9999999999/{H;b n}; p; :n; ${g;s/\n//p}' file
```

Comment: Sorry guys for very late response. 9999999999 would be there always